# Auto-Refresh on content changed shows only one record out of multiples

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

Below code of auto refresh is not giving error but it shows only one record out of multiples when refresh.

But when i include and do not refresh the div it shows all records.

**Like this it shows all records**

```
<div class="m-timeline-3__items">
     <?php include('orders.php'); ?>
</div>
```

**Like this it shows one record:**

```
<div id="newOrderRefresh" class="m-timeline-3__items">
</div>
```

**orders.php**

```
<?php
include ('inc/db.php');

$sqlx4  = "select distinct(order_id) as order_id from orders_placed where status = 0 ";
$sqlx5  = $dba2->query($sqlx4);
while ($sql6    = $sqlx5->fetch_assoc()){

    $sqlx1  = "select count(order_id) as total_items, order_id from orders_placed where status = 0 and order_id in ('".$sql6['order_id']."') ";
    $sqlx2  = $dba2->query($sqlx1);
    $sqlx3  = $sqlx2->fetch_assoc();

    $timeoid        = $sqlx3['order_id'];
    $totalItems =   $sqlx3['total_items'];
?>
<div style="width: 100%;" class="m-timeline-3__item m-timeline-3__item--info">
    <div style="margin-left: 41px; " class="m-timeline-3__item-desc">
        <div style="" class="m-timeline-3__item-text">
            Order # <font color="red"><b><?php echo $timeoid; ?></b></font>, 
            Total Items <font color="black"><b>( <?php echo $totalItems; ?> )</b></font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

.

```
var cacheData;
var data = $('#newOrderRefresh').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'orders.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                cacheData = data;
                $('#newOrderRefresh').html(data);
            }           
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, it might be helpful to see the code for `orders.php` as I assume that is generating the data you want to display

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can i give you the code or attach the file?

Comment: Edit your question and add it

Comment: @RiggsFolly added

Comment: I would start by buffering all the HTML you generate into a variable. Then echo it all out in one lump rather than bit by bit.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for disturbance caused you. I figured out it and resolved .. thanks alot for your kind cooperation. It was an query issue which was causing problem. Query had to be closed as i have added the query here in the question, but it was closed after some data. Thanks alot